# Why some fields are missing from google calendar event list in NodeJS google calendar api?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I have successfully integrated NodeJS backend with google calendar. I retrieve all events from google calendar successfully.

Issue is following: not all fields are present in resulting event list. For example: some fields from `organizer` are missing altogether.

This is my sample response:

```
    {
        "kind": "calendar#event",
        "etag": "\"---\"",
        "id": "---",
        "status": "confirmed",
        "htmlLink": "---",
        "created": "2022-03-28T15:32:53.000Z",
        "updated": "2022-03-28T15:32:53.093Z",
        "creator": {
            "email": "tornike.shavishvili@ngt.ge",
            "self": true
        },
        "organizer": {
            "email": "tornike.shavishvili@ngt.ge",
            "self": true
        },
        "start": {
            "dateTime": "2022-03-28T19:30:00+04:00",
            "timeZone": "Asia/Tbilisi"
        },
        "end": {
            "dateTime": "2022-03-28T20:30:00+04:00",
            "timeZone": "Asia/Tbilisi"
        },
        "iCalUID": "---",
        "sequence": 0,
        "reminders": {
            "useDefault": true
        },
        "eventType": "default"
    }
```

Here are list of all parameters according to google documentation: [Events Resource representations](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#resource)

The above response is from my personal calendar and the visit was created with my account.

I also have calendars that were shared with me. From those calendars, when events are created by different users, the `organizer` field is missing altogether. See example Below:

```
[
  {
    kind: 'calendar#event',    
    etag: '"---"',
    id: '---',
    status: 'confirmed',
    htmlLink: '---',
    updated: '2022-03-29T06:24:21.598Z',
    creator: { email: 'mari.chkonia@signify.ge' },
    start: { dateTime: '2022-03-29T14:00:00+04:00', timeZone: 'Asia/Tbilisi' },
    end: { dateTime: '2022-03-29T15:00:00+04:00', timeZone: 'Asia/Tbilisi' },
    visibility: 'private',
    iCalUID: '---'
  }
]
```

I have researched it for several days but completely out of clue: what could be reason of missing fields? Maybe integration account needs some additional permissions?

I also want to mention that I am impersonating my personal mail, and I am using google API service account authentication.

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question include [example] and show the output you are getting as well as a link to the documentation stating that this is not the output you should be getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** These are remnants of the now-defunct Google+.

##### Summary

Based on your example the missing fields under `organizer` are `displayName` and `id`.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#resource) that you shared mentions that the `organizer.displayName` field only shows *if available*. This is the same for the `organizer.id` field, which should return the "Profile ID".

The question would be: what determines the availability of these fields, and what is a "Profile ID"?

The `organizer.displayName` field is supposedly writable so I tried to manually set it via the [insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert?) API, since there doesn't seem to be an option for it in the UI. The API call was successful, but the field still didn't show up when I tried to retrieve the event afterwards.

This led me to a [report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759234) in Google's issue tracker also claiming inconsistencies on when this field is returned. It appears that `displayName` comes from the organizer's Google+ Profile, if it exists. This would also explain what a "Profile ID" is. The final response by a Googler before closing the report was the following:

> From what I can tell this behavior is consistent with the Google Calendar UI, and there are times when the user's name is not shared. If interested I can work to determine the exact set of rules that govern this behavior, but in general it is working as intended.

Presumably some of the "times when the user's name is not shared" would be something like the Google+ profile being private. Since no one asked to clarify these rules we can no longer know them for sure.

Google+ and its API were [shut down](https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown) and replaced by [Currents](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2019/04/currents-for-gsuite.html) in 2019. This would mean that these fields are just vestiges probably left to avoid breaking old code. If you're interested in correcting the documentation or giving these fields a new purpose you could try to [submit a request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=823906) in Google's issue tracker.

**Edit:** I found one scenario where `displayName` will still show up. If the user has a Currents public profile you will be able to see the field in your responses. Do note that this is not retroactive, so if the user creates a profile it won't show up in past events. Also, Currents is only for paid [Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/googlecurrents/answer/1407609) accounts.

Comment: Hi thank you for this info. I have added use case when organizer filed is missing. Maybe you could give some advice?

Comment: Sure, as you can see in your response, the event visibility is marked as `private`. In this case you won't be able to see the organizer if you're looking at a Calendar that was shared with you. Also, the `organizer` refers to [the Calendar that owns the event](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/10003792). So another scenario where it would be missing is if the user who shared their calendar with you is only an invitee to the event but doesn't actually own the event, and you don't have access to the owner's calendar. I also corrected my answer with a scenario where `displayName` does show.

Comment: The "Currents" suggestion is a big tip - this solved the issue for our organization. We turned on "Currents" for the business, and made sure that the Profile was "active" under Profile Status when viewing from Google Apps for Business.  Problem solved after weeks of fruitless code changes.